# Sprite Kit slow loading time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

i currently have an issue with a game i made and i wanted to ask if there's a solution to it. Basically, my game loads perfectly to the main menu without any problems just as fast as any other application, but when i press the play button, which takes you to the MainGameScene, it takes about 3 - 4 seconds before that scene will appear. It only occurs the first time you press the play button. So if you die, go back to the main menu and hit play again, it loads instantly. So my question is, why does it taking a few seconds to load the MainGameScene? Is there something i missed when coding? Is it not preloading?
-(void)loadTextures {

I have just tried this but the scene will not transition from the loading screen to the main menu scene. Any ideas?

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"obstacle.png","background.png","Ghost.png", nil];
[SKTexture preloadTextures:imageArray withCompletionHandler:^
 {
     SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.75];
     MGLCreateMainMenuScene *scene = [[MGLCreateMainMenuScene alloc] initWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
     scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
     [self.view presentScene:scene transition:reveal];
 }];
```

}

Comment: The first time your game loads, everything is initialised for the first time. On subsequent attempts, these assets are readily available in your memory, hence these do not take time to load. I would suggest you put up a loader with an activity indicator while the game loads.

Comment: Also, how are you preloading the assets in the game?

Comment: 99% chance that texture loading is 99% of the loading time. You can speed it up by using a texture atlas if you don't use one yet.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, I have an empty screen with an empty skscene and its loading for about 2-3 seconds, has some lag. no sprites, no background - nothing. Why?

Comment: Is that counting from when you launch the app? That would be normal. Also it doesn't matter if the scene is empty, if you (pre)load the textures this will take some time. Also try measuring this with a release build without the debugger attached. Some debug flags (if set in the scheme) like malloc guard edges etc. will have a serious impact on performance.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D is there documentation somewhere that shows how to use texture atlas's for loading your game?

Comment: Yes, Sprite Kit reference and programming guide. When using an atlas, you just start using it and remove any individual images you had in the project. Methods like spriteWithImageNamed: will first check for an individual image, and if not found, will try to load an image with that name from the atlas.

Comment: @akashg i don't have anything currently preloading, whats the best way to do it, and to then transition scenes when done?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find any type of solution?

Comment: Do you have any custom fonts in your game? Ones you added to your Xcode project as `.ttf` or similar files.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for preloading is incorrect. Please try this instead:

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[imageArray addObject: [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"obstacle.png"]];
[imageArray addObject: [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[imageArray addObject: [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Ghost.png"]];

[SKTexture preloadTextures:imageArray withCompletionHandler:^
 {
     SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.75];
     MGLCreateMainMenuScene *scene = [[MGLCreateMainMenuScene alloc] initWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
     scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
     [self.view presentScene:scene transition:reveal];
 }];
```